# How to send a multi-part that contain Array of strings and array of files

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am using the following code to send a post  multipart request that contain multi parameters type:

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("**")
    fun sendRequest(
        @Part("ContactType") contactType: RequestBody? = null,
        @Part("Description") description: RequestBody? = null,
        @Part("ServiceProviderId") serviceProviderId: RequestBody? = null,
        @Part("Title") title: RequestBody? = null,
        @Part("Latitude") latitude: RequestBody? = null,
        @Part("Mobile") mobile: RequestBody? = null,
        @Part("Longitude") longitude: RequestBody? = null,
        @Query("MainActivities[]") mainActivities :ArrayList<String>,
        @Part("Files") files: List<MultipartBody.Part>
    ): Observable<SendRequestResponse>
```

Here's how I set the value:

```
        val titleBody = createBodyRequestFromString(title.value ?: "")
        val latitudeBody = createBodyRequestFromString(lat.value ?: "")
        val longitudeBody = createBodyRequestFromString(lng.value ?: "")
        val contactTypeBody = createBodyRequestFromString(contactType.value.toString() ?: "")
        val serviceProviderIdBody = createBodyRequestFromString(serviceProviderId.value ?: "")
        val mobileBody = createBodyRequestFromString(phoneNumber.value ?: "")

        val mainActivitiesBody: ArrayList<RequestBody> = ArrayList()
        createBodyRequestFromString(mainActivities.value?.get(0)).let { mainActivitiesBody.add(it) }

    private fun createBodyRequestFromString(string: String?): RequestBody {
        return RequestBody.create("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull(), string!!)
    }


    private fun addFileAsMultipart() {
        val imagesParts = ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part>(selectedImages.size)

        selectedImages.forEachIndexed { index, file ->
            val requestBody = RequestBody.create("image/jpeg".toMediaTypeOrNull(), file)
            imagesParts.add(
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                    "files",
                    file.name,
                    requestBody
                )
            )
        }}
```

It keep saying:

> @Part parameters using the MultipartBody.Part must not include a part name in the annotation. (parameter #10)

And when I get out of the files, backend can't get my RequestBody values.

How can I send a multi-part that contain array of strings and array of files?

Comment: \\ if my answer works .. please mark it as accepted answer .. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

try this [tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-passing-multiple-parts-along-a-file-with-partmap) helps me alot

as per this tutorial .. you have to change
this line

```
@Part("Files") files: List<MultipartBody.Part> //kotlin
@Part("Files) List<MultipartBody.Part> files //java
```

with this line

```
@Part files: List<MultipartBody.Part> //kotlin
@Part List<MultipartBody.Part> files //java
```

and change this line

```
MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("files",file.name,requestBody)
```

with this line

```
MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("files[]",file.name,requestBody)
```

i hope it works ^_^